# html tables not appearing next to each other, but vertically on top of each other

Tags: html, html-table

What would be causing the following code to stack the tables on top of each other?  I am using no break?

```
<div id="wrapper">

<table>
<tr>yo</tr>
</table>
<table style="float:right;"><tr>yo</tr></table>

</div>
```

Comment: Table rows need to contain a `td` element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="wrapper">
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <table>
     <tr><td>yo</td></tr>
    </table>
   </td>
   <td>
    <table style="float:right;">
     <tr>
      <td>yo</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you float an element, it only affects all the elements that come **after**.

Try giving the first table a `float:left` instead/as well.

Answer (score 0):

Floating an element has two effects:

1. It moves the element to that side
2. It allows content that follows the element to bubble up on the other side

Since the **first** table isn't floating, the second table cannot bubble up beside it.

Answer (score 0):

Put the table you want to float right first and the second table will appear to its left.

Answer (score 0):

Without a valid `td` I'm not surprised that strange things happen.

Try:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>yo</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and check what happens.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<table style="float:left;">
<tr>yo</tr>
</table>


<table style="float:right;">
<tr>yo</tr>
</table>

</div>
```